# Not get expected result os.system

Tags: python, python-3.x

The expected result in *result* variable is **root**. 
version: Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17)

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system("stat -c '%U' /tmp/test")
    root
    0
>>> result = os.system("stat -c '%U' /tmp/test")
    root
>>> print(result)
    0
```

Comment: I think the functionality you're looking for is described here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`os.system` is used to just get the return code, in your case try to use `subprocess.check_output`

```
from subprocess import check_output
result = check_output(["stat","-c","'%U'","/tmp/test"])
print result
root
```

Comment: I think it is correct method but shows error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "stat -c '%U' /tmp/test": "stat -c '%U' /tmp/tes

Comment: try now, added shell = True

Answer (score 1):

From the docs of `os.system`:

> On Unix, the return value is **the exit status of the process** encoded in the format specified for wait()

Your command executes without error, so its exit status is `0`, which is what `system` returns. If you want to get the *output* of the command you run, you'll need to call the command via one of the `subprocess` module's functions.

Answer (score 0):

as per description at [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) link the `os.system()` returns the exit code of the command and not the actual output. Instead of this you can use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module.

Comment: how can I use it in subprocess?
please explain

Comment: please check examples on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output) link